# Using Azure DevOps REST Api how can I get the default branch?

Tags: rest, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

When I use the following API:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/stats/branches?api-version=6.0
```

The response contains a key called **isBaseVersion**.  Does this always indicate the default branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**WARNING: This may be the accepted answer, but it is false. Multiple branches can be marked `isBaseVersion : true`. This field does not indicate the default branch.**

> Does this always indicate the default branch?

Yes. This parameter(`isBaseVersion`) indicates the default branch.

When the value is true, this means that the branch is the default branch.

Comment: This is not true. Multiple branches can be marked as `isBaseVersion: true`. This is even the case in the sample response in Microsoft's own documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/stats/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP#for-all-branches

Comment: Edited this answer to draw others' attention to the fact that it is wrong.